# "She has passed the exam, therefore she can work in the company directly."

Tags: grammaticality

Which of the following two sentences is correct?

> She has passed the exam, therefore she can work in the company directly.

> She has passed the exam and, therefore, she can work in the company directly.

Answer (score 3):

Both are correct. You could replace the comma after "exam" with a semicolon in the first sentence, or add a comma between "exam" and "and" in the second, but both are stylistic preferences more than errors (and in the latter case, you'd end up with rather a lot of commas in a short distance).

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence is an example of comma-splice; using the correct punctuation would require using a semicolon before *therefore*.

> She has passed the exam; therefore, she can work in the company directly.

The second sentence is fine as it is.

> She has passed the exam and, therefore, she can work in the company directly.

Comment: Thanks, but why we could not use comma and need to use the semicolon before "therefore"?

Comment: As said from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_splice), comma splices often arise when writers use [conjunctive adverbs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_adverb) to separate two independent clauses instead of using a coordinating conjunction. A coordinating conjunction is one of the seven words: _for_, _and_, _nor_, _but_, _or_, _yet_, _so_. A conjunctive adverb is a word like _furthermore_, _however_, or _moreover_.

Comment: If you look at the list of conjunctive adverbs, _therefore_ is one of those.